# Using tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabs

I made a password generator app that works well, but I want to update it so it can save passwords.  I want to have one tab where the user sees the generated passwords and has the option to save one of them, and another tab with the saved passwords.  I looked at the developer.android.com tutorials, but I don't like how you have to make a separate activity for each tab.  I've used tabs to create WPF applications using XAML and C#, where I just have to use the TabControl and TabItem in the XAML code. Is it possible to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a separate activity for each tab..  You do, however, have to have a layout for each tab.  You need a `TabHost`, a `TabWidget`, and a `FrameLayout`.  The `TabWidget` and `FrameLayout` have to be children of the `TabHost`, and they also have to have specific ID's assigned to them.  The `TabWidget` has to have the ID of `android.R.id.tabs`.  The `FrameLayout` has to have the ID of `android.R.id.tabcontent`.  Any `View`s or `Layout`s you want to be displayed (for any part of the `TabHost`) have to be added to the `FrameLayout`.  THEN you need to create a `TabSpec` that links everything together.  It looks sorta like this (progmatically)..

```
TabHost host = new TabHost(context);
TabWidget widget = new TabWidget(context);
widget.setID(android.R.id.tabs);
FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context);
frame.setID(android.R.id.tabcontent);
frame.addView(viewForTab1);
frame.addView(viewForTab2);
host.addView(widget);
host.addView(frame);
host.setup();  //must be called when defining a tabhost outside of a tabactivity, iirc..
TabSpec spec;
do {
    spec = host.newTabSpec(uniqueStringReference);
    spec.setContent(viewOrLayoutForTheTab);
    spec.otherStuffYouMightWant();
    host.addTab(spec);
} while (you have tabs to add);
```

Comment: A have a few questions. If I have a TabHost, TabWidget, and FrameLayout already in the main.xml file, couldn't I use findViewById(R.id.nameOfView) instead of creating new objects?  Then I don't think I would have to add the views to the frame or the widget and frame to the TabHost. Also, what is the uniqueStringReference?

Comment: Sorry about the late response..  I'm sure you could use findViewById .. I have not used XML for much, personally - I prefer to do most of my with code so I can use values for the view calculated off the dimensions of the screen.  But what you say would probably work.  The `uniqueStringReference`, I believe, is anything you want it to be .. as long as it's unique.  It's something you use (kinda like an ID for a view) for a reference for the tab if you need to get to it.  At least, I believe that's what it's purpose is.  I haven't looked at the API in a little while.